# How can I find the matrix of affine transformations?

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

I know the points of a triangle: x1 = (0,2), x2 = (-2,-2) and x3 = (2,-2) and the triangle has been scaled, translated and rotated, how can I find the scaling, translation and rotation matrices (assuming homogenous coordinates) if I know one of the transformed points y3 = ((9-√3)/2,(5-√3)/2) which corresponds to the transformation of x3.

I tried multiplying the matrices S, T, and R (STR) * x3 and I got
[image: Matrix multiplied]

But not sure what to do from there.

Comment: I am assuming y3 corresponds to x3

Comment: Translation isn't represented by matrix multiplication, just vector addition.

Comment: Well assuming the use of homogenous coordinates, can't it be done with matrix multiplication?

Comment: You transform has 4 parameters, but if you know the image of only 1 point it gives you only 2 equations. E.g., you can apply arbitrary scaling and rotation, and then use translation to get from x3 to y3.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is not clear why you wish to use homogeneous coordinates, which would mean embedding the Euclidean plane into the projective plane. That can certainly be done and yields very intersting results on what happens to mid-points, perpendicularity and so on in terms of the projective concepts of cross-ratio and harmonic conjugate but your question seems to me one that is more appropriately handled by staying in the Euclidean plane. An affine transformation is one of the form $(x,y) \mapsto (x^{\prime},y^{\prime})$ where $$\begin{bmatrix}x^{\prime}\\y^{\prime} \end{bmatrix}=A\begin{bmatrix}x\\y \end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}e\\f \end{bmatrix}$$ where $A$ is a 2 $\times$ 2 matrix. Thus you have 6 unknowns, viz. $e,f$ and the 4 entries of $A$. If you only know what hapens to one point, you have just two equations, so you have a lof freedom in choosing $A$ and $e,f$. Once you have made such a choice let $k=\sqrt{\vert \det A \vert \space}$. Then  $kI$ is a scaling matrix and $A=(kI)B$ where either $\det B$ =-1 and $B$ corresponds to reflection about a line throuth origin or $\det B$ =1 and $B$ corresponds to a rotation about the origin. Note that if you choose $A$ such that $\det A>0$, then $\det B=1.$